# What am I doing wrong to find this expected value?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If I have 100,000 dollars to invest in stocks, and I can invest 1000 dollars in any particular stock my profit will be 200, 100, 0 and -100 dollars with probability .25 each. There are 100 different stocks to choose from and they all behave independently of each other.

a) How do I find the expected value if I invest 100,000 dollars in one stock and

b) If I invest 1000 in 100 different stocks?

What I did was $$E(X)=100[200*.25+100*.25+0*.25-100*.25]=5000$$

However the actual problem is asking about the probability of profit being 8000 dollars or more and in order to do that I'm assuming the distribution is normal so I'm looking for the $Var(X)$ so I can get the standard deviation. My $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2)$ isn't adding up because im getting a higher $(E(X))^2$ than I am $E(X^2)$. So my expected value must be wrong. Or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your expected value is fine.  If I had to guess, you are squaring the $100$ when you do $E(X)^2$  and not when you do $E(X^2)$, but you don't show your calculation for $E(X^2)$.  For a single stock, the $E(X)=50, E(X^2)=15000, E(X^2)-E(X)^2=12500$, nicely positive.

Answer (score 0):

In the last paragraph you said:

> However the actual problem is asking about the probability of profit being 8000 dollars or more

so I am going to answer this problem. I see two ways of solving this- one is to assume the distribution is normal and integrating the [Gausian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) (If you invest 100 times in different stocks, I will assume that 100 is close enough to infinity so the central limit theorem is true and the distribution is normal). The other way is generating data and just counting how many times the profit is more than 8000.

**Integrating the Gausian**

You already calculated the expected value which is the same as the mean if the distribution is normal $E(X) = 5000$.

To calculate the standard deviation for 1000 dollars invested in a single stock:
$\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{(200-50)^2+(100-50)^2+(0-50)^2+(-100-50)^2}{4}} \approx 122.47$, to calculate the standard deviation for investment in 100 different stocks, the variance needs to be multiplied by 100, after the square root it comes out 10 times bigger:
$\sigma = \sqrt{100\frac{(200-50)^2+(100-50)^2+(0-50)^2+(-100-50)^2}{4}} \approx 1224.7$ Now we have everything to put in the normal distribution formula:
$f(x) = \int_{8000}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2}$
I programmed in python [Riemann integrating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) and calculated the function for bounds 8000 to 20000(after a few sigma, the function is small) with step 0.01 (can share code if someone wants) and got $P(E(X)>8000) \approx 0.715 \% $ (This makes sense- 8000 is about 2.45 $\sigma$ away from the mean, and this percentage approximately resembles [near by sigma values from tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Rules_for_normally_distributed_data)).

**Data generation**

Maybe this is called bootstrapping, I am not sure. Anyways, I programmed to pick 100 numbers from the list [200, 100, 0, -100] and sum them, then compare how many of them are bigger than or equal to 8000. From this approach the result is $\approx 0.39 ... 0.42 \%$. Again, I can share my code if someone is interested. It does seem a bit weird to me that these two solutions differ, does the assumption of a normal distribution really make this difference? When I make the step smaller or take larger bounds the result changes only in the forth significant digit...

Thank you for the question, this was interesting to investigate!